# Renaming a file on HDFS works in local mode but not in cluster mode

Tags: java, hadoop, hdfs

I have an object in charge of opening a file on HDFS to write. This object renames the file it just wrote once the `close()` method is invoked.
The mechanism works when running in local mode, but it fails to rename the file in cluster mode.

```
//Constructor
public WriteStream() {
    path = String.format("in_progress/file");
    try {
        OutputStream outputStream = fileSystem.create(new Path(hdfs_path+path), new Progressable() {public void progress() { System.out.print("."); }
            });
        writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void close() {
    String newPath = String.format("%s_dir/%s_file", date, timestamp);
    try {
        fileSystem.rename(new Path(hdfs_path+path), new Path(hdfs_path+newPath));
        writer.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Did you experience that before ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently `FileSystem.rename(Path)` creates missing directories on the path when executed in local mode, but it does not when run in cluster mode.
This code works in both modes:

```
public void close() {
    String dirPath = String.format("%s_dir/", date, timestamp);
    String newPath = String.format("%s_dir/%s_file", date, timestamp);
    try {
        fileSystem.mkdir(new Path(hdfs_path+dirPath));
        fileSystem.rename(new Path(hdfs_path+path), new Path(hdfs_path+newPath));
        writer.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just curious, but how can you rename a file that officially doesn't exist (because you're still writing at that point)?

The fix is to rename after the file has been completed. That is, when you invoked the close method.

So your code should look like this:

```
public void close() {
    String newPath = String.format("%s_dir/%s_file", date, timestamp);
    try {
        writer.close();
        fileSystem.rename(new Path(hdfs_path+path), new Path(hdfs_path+newPath));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: @ngrislain what does not work? Do you see an exception in the logs?

Comment: It does not move the file. But I found the solution. On the local FS, rename creates the intermediate directories when they do not exist. I just added a fileSystem.mkdir().